# Parameters to TypeORM annotations

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm using an ORM framework in TypeScript (TypeORM), and I can set somethings using annotations (like @entity(database: '')).

Can I receive the parameter value from an annotation from a .env file or a class with constants?

I tryed:

```
@entity(database: process.env.DATA_BASE_NAME)
class UserEntity {...}
```

With no sucess =/
Because at this moment my .env was not instantiate yet =/

But it works fine:

```
@entity(database: 'Users')
class UserEntity {

  dotenv.config();

  @(column: process.env.TABLE_USER_COL_ID_NAME, ...)
  private id: number;
}
```

Some tip to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

you should read .env file at the begining of your file, not in the class.

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```

and you can put this line just in your main file, eg, server.ts, and you'll have access to all the env variables.